# I cannot get the expected result

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a program that uses a while loop to determine how long it takes for an investment to double at a given interest rate. The input will be an annualized interest rate, and the output is the number of years it takes an investment to double but no matter what i put in i keep getting 1:

```
def main():
    I= eval(input("Enter your annualized interest rate: "))
    i=0
    z=1
    while z<2:
        i=i+1
        z=(z*(1+I))
    if z>=2:
        print (i)
```

Comment: Why do you eval the input?

Comment: Your input has no impact on the value of the variable you print.

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of the `eval` and replace it with an `int` or `float` depending on whether the interest rate or integer or not:

```
I = float(input("Enter your annualized interest rate: "))
```

then divide the percentage by 100:

```
z = z * (1 + I / 100.0)
```

You also don't need the last `if` statement as `z` will always be larger than or equal to 2 to get out of the `while` loop.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Thanks for the heads up. `int()` will work with both versions.

Comment: As written, the OP was probably entering a float, but it isn't specified.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Selcuk is excellent and it's the one I would accept.
Now, since I have written down a few lines, here is some code that may come in handy:

```
from sys import argv

def f(I, factor):
    I = 1 + I/100.0
    z = 1
    years = 0
    while z < factor:
        z *= I
        years += 1
    return years


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(argv) < 3:
        print "usage: %s rate factor"
        exit(1)
    I = float(argv[1])
    factor = float(argv[2])
    print f(I, factor)
```

Comment: I = 1 + I/100.0 is quite confusing IMHO. Variable names shouldn't be recycled.

Comment: Agreed, could use another var. The point was showing to avoid repeating the calculation within the loop.